# How to find Nal header in h.264 RTP packet

Tags: header, h.264, rtp

I need to find the NAL header by parsing a RTP packet where each NAL unit is encapsulated into one RTP packet, then i parse the Nal header to know whether it's a PPS unit or not. I tried the following but i got no result:

```
       dataBuffer = (char*)MESSAGE_ReturnPacket(msg);

       byte * hdr = (byte*)dataBuffer + RTP_HDR_SIZE; //dataBuffer contains  the RTP packet

        RTPParsing((byte*)dataBuffer,rp,hdr);

        if (rp.nal_type == 8 )
        {
            printf("\n  PPS is found \n");

        }
        else
       {
       printf("\n No PPS is found\n");

        }
```

where

```
    int RTPParsing(byte *pData,RTPpacket_t &rp, byte *hdr)
    {
    if ((pData[0] & 0xc0) != (2 << 6)){
    printf("[RTP] version is incorrect! dump = 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 0x%x 

    \n",pData[0], pData[1], pData[2], pData[3]);
    return 0;
    }

/* parse RTP header */

rp.v = (pData[0] & 0xc0) >> 6; /* protocol version */
rp.p = (pData[0] & 0x40) >> 5; /* padding flag */
rp.x = (pData[0] & 0x20) >> 4; /* header extension flag */
rp.cc = (pData[0] & 0x0f);  /* CSRC count */
rp.m = (pData[1] & 0x80) >> 7; /* marker bit */
rp.pt = (pData[1] & 0x7F); //Payload Type
rp.seq = ntohs (((unsigned short *) pData)[1]);    /* sequence number */
rp.timestamp = ntohl (((unsigned int *) pData)[1]); /* timestamp */
rp.ssrc = ntohl (((unsigned int *) pData)[2]);  /* synchronization source */
rp.nal_type = (hdr[1] & 0x1F); // get NAL unit's type

if (rp.cc)

    {
    for (int i = 0; i < rp.cc; i++)
    {
        //fprintf (out, " csrc: 0x%08x",ntohl (((unsigned int *) data)[3 + i]));
    }
    }
    return 0;
    }
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

According to [RFC6184](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6184#section-5.6) in single NAL unit mode, the "The first byte of a NAL unit co-serves as the
RTP payload header"

You offset is incorrect (1 instead of 0):

```
rp.nal_type = (hdr[1] & 0x1F); // get NAL unit's type
```

Also, hard-coding `RTP_HDR_SIZE` as 12 (if that's what you're doing) could cause issues since the size of the header may vary based on extension headers, CSRCs, etc.